# Show window.confirm for prevent changing the URL

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-hooks, onbeforeunload

Needs to prevent changing url from my component. So, nees to show a message, and if user choose cancel - don't change the URL, if OK - change the URL. How I can make this logic in next 13.4

It's my current logic, but it doesn't work. I even don't see the window.confirm message

```
useEffect(() => {
const handleBeforeUnload = (event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
const mess = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?');
event.returnValue = mess;
if (!mess) {
event.preventDefault();
       }
     };

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);

return () => {
window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, even when I try in in the StackOverflow snippet.

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
  const unsavedChanges = true;
  if (unsavedChanges) {
    const confirmationMessage = 'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave?';
    event.returnValue = confirmationMessage;
    return confirmationMessage; 
  }
});
```

```html
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'https://example.com/'">Go to example.com</button>
<button onclick="window.location.reload()">Reload</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have a little bit another case. Needs to show message, when user choose links from another components (like header/footer) on page. I have problems in described case.

Comment: Well, can't you just add the useEffect in the head of the app? That way, the moment the app loads the event listener is added to the window and it should work for any link in the app.